# Is there a proof (maybe formulated by Feferman) which says that a proof about the (in)consistency of ZFC is unachievable?

Tags: set-theory, alternative-proof

Is there a proof (maybe formulated by Feferman) which says that a proof about the (in)consistency of ZFC is unachievable?
A professor said it to me a long time ago, but I don't have any references.
Thanks (and sorry for my english).

Comment: Maybe a dim recollection of the second incompleteness theorem?

Comment: I don't think a proof that inconsistency of ZFC is unachievable could exist: that would be a proof of *con*sistency, contradicting Goedel, right?

Comment: @Qfwfq: the comment is that (informally speaking) if ZFC is consistent then it cannot prove its own consistency. In that sense a proof of consistency could be "unachievable".

Answer (score 1):

There are six mentions of incompleteness and eight of sets on Professor Feferman’s publications page, https://math.stanford.edu/~feferman/papers.html, but I’m not sure that any of them are what you’re asking for.  Could you instead be thinking of a result by a different Stanford logician, that the “C” in ZFC is independent of ZF:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Cohen#Contributions_to_mathematics?